# Why typescript emits error compilation in react-script with keywords?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, keyword, react-scripts

#### I have the very strange problems with typescript with react-scripts

```
 Line 5:16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  3 |  class AutoUpdateBase<TBinding> implements IAutoUpdate<TBinding>{
  4 |
> 5 |      protected binding?: (arg: TBinding) => void;
    |                ^
  6 |
  7 |      resolveValue(): TBinding{ throw new Error('Not implements'); };
  8 |      reciveValue(value: TBinding): void{ throw new Error('Not implements'); };
```

...That could be happening??

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly your environment is not properly set up to load or transpile typescript, and the error you're seeing arises from it trying to interpret typescript as javascript (which doesn't have the protected keyword).

However, because your question includes almost none of the context needed to answer it, such as what build command was running which generated the error, in what tool, in what react hosting environment, it's pretty much impossible to provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly, I use an environment with react-scripts only, let's say for the development part, that the command is `npm start` which in turn calls the * start * of` react-scripts`, maybe I have something bad in the tsconfig.ts, because the vscode IDE does not issue any issue about that error

Comment: Probably the typescript is fine (hence VSCode doesn't complain), but whatever is trying to run the typescript file as javascript is bad. We can't see anything of your configuration or how it's run, so it's impossible to say more.

Comment: this is the repo https://github.com/oliver021/post-io/tree/develop, here there is all configurations

Comment: There is an issue installing from the repository https://github.com/oliver021/post-io/issues/1